# Number of Integers less than x in a subarray

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given an array A[1..n] and Q queries on that array.
Each query is of the format (x a b), and for every query I need to find out, how many elements in the sub-array (a,b) of main array denoted by A[a..b] are less than x.
How to perform this job efficiently ? 
OR If required what kind of data structures to build on top of array, to perform the job efficiently ? 
Limits : 
n <= 10^6 
Q <= 10^4

Comment: Show what you have done, I mean, code.

Comment: I was planning to use segment tree some how. But the idea I have is quite space inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HINTS

Use a [Fenwick tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) to store a cumulative histogram of which values you have seen.

Turn your queries (x a b) into a F(x,a)-F(x,b-1) where F(x,a) counts numbers less than x in the range 0..a.

Sort these F(x,a) queries by a.

Then iterate over the array index i, inserting element A[i] into the Fenwick tree, and answering any F(x,a) queries that have a==i.

Comment: The solution using Fenwick Tree as you proposed will be feasible, only if the x is same for all the queries, but that is not so .

Comment: I agree that x is not the same for all queries.  However, I believe that this solution works with varying x (because the Fenwick tree allows us to answer questions of the form "How many have we seen of value <= x?" for any value of x).

Comment: but then, if we try to solve the problem like that, then how the information about sub-array is utilized ? The problem has to be solved on the sub-array. Maybe you can elaborate more.